# 80s-90s science fiction movie where a family's home becomes like a garden due to the parents' experiments

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's about a family who lives on Earth. The father and mother are scientists, experiment with some sort of flora and fauna (during the movie the whole house becomes like a garden). The parents or one of them transforms into a swarm spore being.

The conditions on Earth are high temperature through the solarflare (or something like), the teenage son goes one day to school or out and is burned but heals quick (or isn't affected by the sun at all I can't remember).

One day he goes to a waterfall or river and sees a beautiful girl who becomes his girlfriend.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Could be [*Habitat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitat_(film)):

[image: Poster for "Habitat," captioned "Welcome to a living Hell." The poster depicts a human-like head with yellow, vertically-slit eyes and strands of long curly red hair. There are vine growing out of the mouth, worms erupting out of the right cheek, insects crawling across the forehead, left cheek and shoulder, and the scalp and torso are growing a variety of plants and mosses]

> In a future where the Earth's ozone layer is severely decreased in size, the Symes family is on the run from the father's former employers and the government. Hank Symes (Tchéky Karyo) a molecular biologist, has become so obsessed with saving the world that he has placed his entire family's lives in danger. They stop in a desert community to hide out and continue work when a terrible accident occurs that transforms Hank into a fantastic ethereal lifeform and begins changing the house into a huge botanical biosphere entity which has the ability to threaten all who enter.
>
> Their son Andreas (Balthazar Getty), however, is experiencing things from a teenager's point of view and doesn't know how he will be able to attend the local school, let alone fit in with any of the local kids as they all see him as some weirdo that just wandered into town. No matter what Andreas feels, his father is still around him, changing things for him and others and eventually even Andreas will come to see that in this strange time he is living that miracles still can happen.